# c unsigned integer bitshift

Tags: c, bit-shift

i have this code to split an unsigned 32 bit integer into a char array with each element of the array relating to 8 bits of the integer:

```
unsigned char result[4];
result[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
result[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
result[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
result[3] = value & 0xFF;
```

what changes would i need to make to split the 32 bit unsigned integer into 3 values: the 1st value relating to the first 8 bits, the 2nd value relating to the 2nd 8 bits and the 3rd value relating to the last 16 bits?

thanks

Comment: Which 8 bits out of the last 16 do you want?  If you are storing the data into 8-bit storage, something has to be lost.

Comment: i don't want to lose any of them. at the moment i am splitting a UInt32 into 4 bytes and creating directories that correspond to these each of the bytes. so the 8 MSBs is the top level, the next 8 bits being the 2nd level, the 3rd set being the 3rd level and the 8 LSBs making up the 4th level. I'd like to just use 3 levels instead, with the first 2 levels being calculated as before and the last level containing the 16 LSBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont call them the first/last bits. Refer to them by their significance.

```
unsigned short result[3];
result[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
result[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
result[2] = value & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Why would you need to `& 0xFF` for `result[0]`?

Comment: its not needed, it would only be needed if value was signed. also it matched the format of the other lines.

Comment: @RSahu:  It is to prevent future errors when/if the code is slightly modified by someone who does not completely understand it.